# ComputeGCD Dafny

Tags: greatest-common-divisor, dafny

Hi I am trying to prove that the code I write will return the  GreatestCommonDivisor  (ComputeGCD) with Dafny.
but i get stack . I dont undrstand how to prove it , and i cant change the  ComputeGCD
requires and  ensures . any Help please .

```
predicate CommonDivisor(a: nat, b: nat, c: nat)
{
  c > 0 && c <=a && c <=b && a%c == b%c == 0 // i add that c<=a && c<=b 
}

predicate GreatestCommonDivisor(a: nat, b: nat, c: nat)
{
    CommonDivisor(a, b, c) &&
    forall d: nat :: CommonDivisor(a, b, d) ==> d <= c 
}



lemma {:verify false}  GreatestCommonDivisorHeper (a: nat , b:nat , c: nat)
    requires a > 0 && b > 0  
    ensures GreatestCommonDivisor( a, b, c)
{}


    method {:verify false} ComputeGCD(a: nat, b: nat) returns (i: nat)
    requires a > 0 && b > 0
    ensures GreatestCommonDivisor(a, b, i)
    { 
     var x: int;
        i := a;
        x := b;
    assert i == a  && x ==b;
      while (x != i)
      invariant   i > 0 && x > 0 
      decreases x + i 
        {
          if (i > x)
           {
             assert i > x;
             i := i - x;
            }
            else{
                assert  i < x ; 
             x := x - i;
            }
          
        }
         assert a > 0 && b > 0 ;
         assert GreatestCommonDivisor(b - a, a, i); 
         GreatestCommonDivisorHeper(a,b,i);


        // assert  GreatestCommonDivisor(a, b, i) == GreatestCommonDivisor(a,b - a, i);
    }
```

Comment: Hi I did prove this function at the end , using the help of leino.science/papers/krml279.html ,

Comment: If you can post an answer explaining where you were stuck and what you figured out, it might be helpful to others in the future!